# Reload all resources after Locale change in Android

Tags: android, localization, locale

I have a `preferenceFragment` with `PreferenceList` in which the user selects the new Language for the app UI.
I want the whole resources to be refreshed and reloaded with the new language.  (as if the app was restarted with the newly selected language)
As i've read, the `configurationChanged` by its default should restart the `Activity` or whatever is running, but it doesn't seem to happen. (I've added a `Toast` in the `onCreate` of the activity containing the `preferenceFragment` and it isn't called when the configuration changed.
Here is the handling of the Language change within the `preferenceFragment` :

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    if (getString(R.string.shared_options_select_language_key).equals(key)) {
        Toolkit.setApplicationLanguage(getActivity(), getActivity().getBaseContext());
    }
```

Here is the code for `setApplicationLanguage()`:

```
public static void setApplicationLanguage(Context ctx, Context baseCtx) {

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);

    String langKey = ctx.getString(R.string.shared_options_select_language_key);
    String langDefault = ctx.getString(R.string.shared_options_select_language_default_value);
    String appLanguage = preferences.getString(langKey, langDefault);

    Locale locale = null;
    if (appLanguage.equals(langDefault)) {                
    locale = new Locale(Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage());
    } else {
        String[] languageInfo = appLanguage.split("_");
        if (languageInfo.length > 1) {
            locale = new Locale(languageInfo[0], languageInfo[1]);
        } else {
            locale = new Locale(appLanguage);
        }
    }
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;

    baseCtx.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, baseCtx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Comment: Your activity isn't restarting because that's not how you set the locale in android.  Locale.setDefault only effects your app's default locale variable.  The activity only restarts if the system locale is changed.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan , can you please refer me to a correct example of changing the Locale in Android ?

Comment: @Artoo Detoo , this is not an activity, it is preferenceFragment, how can I finish and restart it ?

Comment: have you find any solution? same problem here